# How to utilize server-side data annotation with client-side programming like jsRender

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, asp.net-web-api, jsrender

Before we have WebAPI in MVC4 and before jsRender turns beta, we generate forms using Server-side programming. That is, add in Data Annotations on the view model, then generate a form with a lot of `@Html.EditorFor` and `@Html.LabelFor`. (If you are an MVC programmer, you know what I mean.) Then jQuery validation will help us do data-validation on the client-side, and the DataAnnotation attributes do the job on the server side, by checking `Model.IsValid`. Everything is fine.

Now we have `WebAPI`. Most of the examples are to use Javascript to call Ajax to the `WebAPI` actions to transfer the form data (mostly in json) between the server and the client. jsRender (or other type of templating library) is used to present the data.

I like the idea of making Ajax calls to avoid unnecessary full page rendering. But the main difficult is, since the form is prepared as a template, which binds to data on the client side, there is no way to combine the server-side techniques like DataAnnotation together with the jQuery-validation. And we cannot generate a template using `@Html.EditorFor`. It appears that we lose many great benefits that we had before in MVC3.

So, how do you experts handle this? Do you completely dump the server-side technique and just write out everything in the template for client-side use?

If we can only do everything on the client-side, how can we make the use of jQuery validation? Do we add those `data-val-xxx` tags manually?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Taking an AJAX approach towards ASP.NET MVC does **not** rule out the use of ASP.NET validation features. However, you do have to write your own server-side and client-side architecture to deal with these scenario's. Basically, you want your Web API to be able to throw validation messages for any method. Moreover, you want your client-side JavaScript to be able to handle these messages at any time.

In a ASP.NET MVC + Knockout application I am currently developing, I am doing just that. It involves:

- **Server-side**. A custom `ActionFilterAttribute` that translates model validation errors to JSON
- **Client-side**. Some JavaScript trickery to interpret the validation errors.

On every REST-call I make to the server, I check the HTTP status code on return. `200` means success and the application carries on as normal. `400` means Bad Request, which means one or more validation messages were returned.

In case of a `400`, the body of the response contains a JSON-array with all the validation messages. These messages are simple tuples consisting of the name of the input element and an error message.

I added a new `data-val-server` attribute that always invalidates the input element it is set on. The data I get from the server tells me on what elements to put the attribute. The value of the attribute is the error message which also comes from the server. After that, I simply initiate clientside validation which will parse the form, invalidate the form and view the appropriate messages.

Comment: Impressive. You appear to point to the right direction. But it surely sounds like a lot of work! Do you have to create an individual `EditorTemplate` for each type of data?

Comment: Oops. I have taken out the bit about custom EditorTemplates. That part is only used to automatically generate Knockout bindings and has nothing to do with validation.

Comment: I've expanded my original answer a bit. Yes it took a bit of work to develop it all, but in my project we're talking about 100+ API's that all may or may not throw validation errors. So, for my project, the effort paid off. The client-side architecture is about 200 lines of code, while the server-side ActionFilterAttribute is about 30 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

@Martin Devillers someone did it here: http://sixgun.wordpress.com/2012/03/28/asp-net-web-api-validation-with-data-annotations/

Comment: please do not post only a single link !